# Pyspark reduceByKey to return list of tuples

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have an rdd that goes like this :

```
rdd = [((uid1), (product1, price1, date1)),
       ((uid1), (product2, price2, date2))]
```

I want the output to look like this :

```
reduced_rdd = [((uid1), ((product1, price1, date1), (product2, price2, date2)))]
```

So I tried to do something like :

```
reduced_rdd = rdd.reduceByKey(lambda a,b: a+b)
```

But the output is not what I want :

```
reduced_rdd = [((uid1), (product1, price1, date1, product2, price2, date2))]
```

Cause those tuples concatenate when I use the + operator and if I try to append them in a list I get an ugly nested list.
How can I get a nice reduced rdd where the values are nice and quite in their own tuples?

Answer (score 0):

Remember that a tuple with only one element must still be denoted as `(tuple,)` so all you have to do is use as your parameter function

```
lambda a,b: (a,) + (b,)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
rdd.groupByKey().mapValues(tuple)
```